# OS - memory management - paging

Tags: paging

Consider a memory management system with two levels of paging in which a logical address is 32 bits which include 9bits for the first level table, 11 bits for the second level and the other for displacement.

What is the size of each page?
What is the maximum number of pages per process?

Can you please help me with that? THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of the page comes from the number of bits in the displacement, which is `32 - (9 + 11)` or `12`. The page size is `1 << 12` or `4096`

The number of pages is `1 << (9 + 11)`, which is `1 << 20` or `1,048,576`